# Gradle generated buildSrc + Kotlin = how do I upgrade to Java 17?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm starting a new Kotlin project, and I used Gradle 7.2 to generate the project structure and the buildSrc scripts. I'm not including them here because I have not changed them - I'm just using whatever Gradle generated.

I'm getting the following message as part of the build:

`'compileJava' task (current target is 17) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.`

I can't find where in the buildSrc and the generated Gradle files the 1.8 target is set. How can I tell the Kotlin compiler to use the Java 17 target?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to address that from Kotlin 1.5.30 is to use the [Java Toolchain](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1530.html#support-for-java-toolchains) feature:

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for me. I gave up on using the buildSrc generated files and went back to using a project level gradle build file. Thanks anyway.